# Ruby on Rails routing for variable controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, variables, routes, match

I have a URL I want to be able to redirect to.

Something similar to:

> "http://localhost:3000/username/admin/page".

I have a match in routes.rb as:

```
  match ':account/admin/:page' => "admin#index"
```

I have redirect code:

```
redirect_to :controller => account.username, :action=>"admin", :page=>"index"
```

This, however comes up with a routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"admin", :controller=>"sdunn", :page=>"index"}
```

I know what I have done is wrong, but how can I fix this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Route is expecting 2 parameters, first one is :account, second is :page, i think you are only passing :page. I would add :as => 'some_name' to your route and then use _path :

routes.rb

```
match ':account/admin/:page' => "admin#index", :as => 'my_route'
```

controller:

```
redirect_to my_route_path(@user, @page)
```

my_route_path could be something different depending on your exact route file, so use

```
rake routes | grep my_route
```

to see exact name, then add _path to the end.